# Changes to Stream Provider after migrating to null safety version Provider 5.0.0

Tags: dart, flutter-provider, dart-null-safety, flutter-streambuilder

I have migrated to dart null safety version. The command in migrate function fixed most issues. However, I have a Stream Provider which handles the User Session using Firebase. After the migration to Provider version 5.0.0 the app is crashing. Below is my main class.

```
Future<void> main() async {
WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
await EasyLocalization.ensureInitialized();
await Firebase.initializeApp();

runApp(EasyLocalization(
 child: MyApp(),
 path: "assets/langs",
 saveLocale: true,
 supportedLocales: [
  Locale('en', 'US'),
  Locale('en', 'GB'),
  Locale('es', 'ES'),
 ],
));
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
// This widget is the root of your application.
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return MultiProvider(
  providers: [
    Provider<AuthenticationProvider>(
      create: (_) => AuthenticationProvider(FirebaseAuth.instance),
    ),
    StreamProvider(
        create: (context) =>
            context.read<AuthenticationProvider>().authState,
        initialData: null,
        child: Authenticate())
  ],
  child: ScreenUtilInit(
    builder: () => MaterialApp(
      builder: (context, child) {
        return ScrollConfiguration(
          //Removes the whole app's scroll glow
          behavior: MyBehavior(),
          child: child!,
        );
      },
      title: 'SampleApp',
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      theme: theme(),
      localizationsDelegates: context.localizationDelegates,
      supportedLocales: context.supportedLocales,
      locale: context.locale,
      home: Authenticate(),
      routes: routes,
    ),
  ),
);
}
}

class Authenticate extends StatelessWidget {
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
final firebaseUser = context.watch<User>();

if (firebaseUser != null) {
  FirebaseFirestore.instance
      .collection('user')
      .doc(firebaseUser.uid)
      .get()
      .then((value) {
    UserData.name = value.data()!['name'];
    UserData.age = value.data()!['age'];
  });
  return View1();
}
return View2();
}
}

class MyBehavior extends ScrollBehavior {
@override
Widget buildViewportChrome(
  BuildContext context, Widget child, AxisDirection axisDirection) {
return child;
}
}
```

The app is crashing with the following exception

The following ProviderNotFoundException was thrown building Authenticate(dirty):
Error: Could not find the correct Provider above this Authenticate Widget

This happens because you used a `BuildContext` that does not include the provider
of your choice. There are a few common scenarios:

- You added a new provider in your `main.dart` and performed a hot-reload.
  To fix, perform a hot-restart.
- The provider you are trying to read is in a different route.

  Providers are "scoped". So if you insert of provider inside a route, then
  other routes will not be able to access that provider.
- You used a `BuildContext` that is an ancestor of the provider you are trying to read.

  Make sure that Authenticate is under your MultiProvider/Provider.
  This usually happens when you are creating a provider and trying to read it immediately.

Comment: same issue here, have you solve this?

Answer (score 1):

The answer is very simple. The variable that I was trying to listen to should be nullable.

So, basically

```
final firebaseUser = context.watch<User?>();
```